# Composition vs inheritance for iOS base view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

In general, I've heard its better to use composition than inheritance, but it's not always clear to me how to do that.  I want to create some functionality that's common across all of my view controllers (I want to listen for an NSNotification, and call a method if it receives the notif).

My idea is to create a BaseViewController that each UIViewController extends from.  I'd love to solve this any other way than inheritance for many reasons

- Some view controllers extend UIViewController and some extend UITableViewController
- If I write it in swift, objc view controllers can't subclass it
- Normal reasons for comp over inheritance - easier to understand the behavior

My question is - how do I accomplish this without copy and pasting a ton of code into each viewcontroller?  I could obviously insert a line into each view controllers viewDidLoad method, to add a listener, and into each view controllers delloc, but I'd really rather avoid this.  Is there other techniques that could make this cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2.0 you can use protocol with default method implementations. But in this case is inheritance the best approach for me.

Answer (score -1):

According to me, it will be better to implement some functionality which is common across all ViewControllers by using **Singleton Class**.

Create a simple swift file having Singleton class in it and implement common functions in it which you want to access anywhere. Create a shared instance for that class and by using this shared instance, you can call any function in any ViewController of your application. So that you can reuse the code without copy-paste.